# Stiching together two sqlite tables based on timestamp (with tolerances)

Tags: python, database, sqlite, datetime, join

Given two sqlite tables of information from two different real life sources (which are timestamped). I'm trying to stitch together TABLE_A and TABLE_B based on the closest timestamps. I'm looking to do this in a way so that later queries (joins) are "quick".

My general idea with this is 2 steps:

1) Look for timestamps that exists in both tables, and update a reference column (TABLE_A.ref_timestamp) with that timestamp.

2) IF TABLE_A.timestamp doesn't exists in TABLE_B, find the next closest and write that reference time into TABLE_A.ref_timestamp

- both tables have an unix epoch timestamp as a column

What I'm trying to do is this (in pseudo SQLite):

1) Update TABLE_A.ref_timestamp with TABLE_A.timestamp where timestamp=? IF timestamp EXISTS in TABLE_B.timestamp

- Obviously this doesn't work since "IF" doesn't exist in SQLite

2) UPDATE TABLE_A.ref_timestamp WHERE timestamp=? WITH(SELECT FROM TABLE_B WHERE datetime BETWEEN ?+tolerance AND ?-tolerance ORDER BY ABS(?-datetime) LIMIT 1)

- The idea here is do a rough cut with BETWEEN and pick the closest one in that range, If nothing is found NULL is okay.
- This wouldn't work due to the lack of "WITH"
- The tolerance would be given as a config

My solutions have either not worked or been plagued with syntax errors, and I was wondering if anyone in SO has run across this and has some insight.

Edit with example:

```
TABLE_A:
(timestamp,ref_timestamp)
123.0,NULL
124.0,NULL
125.0,NULL
8000.0,NULL

TABLE_B
(timestamp)
122.5
124.0
125.0
```

After running the "zippering" TABLE_A would contain the following:

```
TABLE_A:
123.0,122.5
124.0,124.0
125.0,125.0
8000.0,NULL
```

Thanks to CL for the solution. It was missing a "table_b." in the ABS function:

```
UPDATE table_a
SET ref_timestamp = (SELECT timestamp
                 FROM (SELECT timestamp,
                              abs(table_b.timestamp - table_a.timestamp) AS diff
                       FROM table_b
                       WHERE timestamp BETWEEN table_a.timestamp - 42 AND table_a.timestamp + 42)
                 ORDER BY diff
                 LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: I should mention this is done inside a python program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WITH is available since SQLite 3.8.3.

Anyway, this can be done by using the correct SQL syntax and a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```sql
UPDATE table_a
SET ref_timestamp = (SELECT timestamp
                     FROM (SELECT timestamp,
                                  abs(timestamp - table_a.timestamp) AS diff
                           FROM table_b
                           WHERE timestamp BETWEEN table_a.timestamp - 42 AND table_a.timestamp + 42)
                     ORDER BY diff
                     LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: After running the above, the results in table_a.ref_timestamp were always 42 less than table_a.timestamp. 

ie:

`123.0 81.0;
124.0 82.0`

the values of 81 and 82 exist in table_b. Could this be due to the ORDER BY diff command?